# Finding double-byte white spaces in SQL table

Tags: sql, whitespace, double-byte

I have some rows in my SQL table that contain single byte space characters, and some that contain double byte space characters. I need to identify rows with double byte characters to fix them in the user interface.

My first thought is to use `charindex` and `substring` to isolate the space from the rest of the text `(SUBSTRING(@SomeField, charindex('　', @SomeField),1))` and then use `DataLength` to see if it was double byte or single byte, but it appears that's not going to work. It appears it's giving the same value for both single-byte and double-byte spaces.

```
SELECT  DATALENGTH('　') --double byte space
, DATALENGTH(' ') --single byte space
, LEN('　') --double byte space
, LEN(' ') --single byte space
```

Comment: Just use LIKE on the column that may have the double space. E.g. SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE DoubleSpaceColName LIKE '%  %';

Comment: Unfortunately, that is still finding both single byte and double byte spaces. 
Both `CASE WHEN FieldWithDB LIKE ('%　%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` and `CASE WHEN FieldWithDB LIKE ('% %') THEN 1 ELSE 0 end` return a value of 1.

Comment: @DerickStephensen By "double-byte white space" do you mean something other than two ordinary consecutive spaces equivalent to ASCII character 32?

Comment: And you can always `cast(col as varbinary(200))` to examine exactly what code points are stored, and share the results here.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Correct. I'm trying to search a name field that contains English and Japanese entries. English entries have the first and last name separated by a regular space (ascii 32). Some of the Japanese names are separated by a double byte white space character. Here's an example I found on another forum that might help to clarify:

" " <--- this is a single-byte white space.
"　" <--- this is a double-byte white space.
"日本 観光" <--- this is a search phrase which contains a single-byte white space.
"日本　観光" <--- this is a search phrase which contains a double-byte white space.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Forgive me, i'm not real familiar with varbinary and don't really know what i'm looking for. This is the output when I cast an example value as varbinary: 0x9F53307500306E6F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That character U+3000 or `select cast(0x0030 as nchar(1))` is apparantly called "Ideographic Space".

You simply need to use unicode literals when using it in code.  Both `like` and `charindex` work fine. But since it's semantically just a space, most collations will not distinguish between U+0020 (a regular space) and U+3000.  So you also need to use a binary collation (or have your database or column set to use one).  EG

```
select 1 where N'原田　潮' like N'%　%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2

select charindex(N'　' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2, N'原田　潮') 


select 1 where N'原田　潮' like N'% %' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2

select charindex(N' ' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2 , N'原田　潮')
```

outputs

```
-----------
1


-----------
3


-----------


-----------
0
```